# Changing SharePoint Files Link in Outlook

Tags: sharepoint-online, outlook, links

Good Day,

I'm trying to change the "Files" link that SharePoint Group members will see in Outlook.  My organization uses this button almost exclusively to access their Shared Document Library files, most of them do not know another way (It's a work in progress).

**Is there a way to change the link location of this Outlook Group "Files" button?  I'm trying to direct it to a different SharePoint Document Library.**

https://gyazo.com/bebfaff0faf4925e4153acfa61e6ef72

An image for reference above.

*Disclaimer:* I'm a novice at SharePoint Online and realize that there are MANY restrictions/changes in this version over others.  So if this is yet another thing that I cannot do, I understand.  Any work-around is appreciated.

**EDIT:** I still have not found a solution for this.  The reason I need to do this is because this instance of SharePoint was not set up well.  So all departments use Document Libraries and nothing else, and all of them have their own site and Doc Lib.  I am making a centralized location for their documents so we can keep them more secure, and I need to change that button for them in Outlook so it re-directs to the correct place.  Suggestions?

-Cheers!

Comment: Hello, please clarify, do you want to change the 'Files' link to point to any other document library than 'Shared Documents'? Or, do you want to change the location of the link in Outlook menu?

Comment: Added to the Question.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Office 365 groups (which are not created from Yammer), will have a group Outlook mailbox, a SharePoint team site (including Shared Documents library), Planner, One Note etc. These apps are interrelated to create an appropriate collaboration environment for the team members.

'Files' link in Outlook, are meant for sharing files among members only, keeping it in a centralized location, i.e. SharePoint. This feature is now available in Teams and Yammer as well, where the shared files are stored into SharePoint team sites's 'Shared Documents' library.

This can not be customized from Outlook. If you want to increase the adoption of SharePoint in your Organization then you should focus on the robust document management and collaboration capabilities and also highlight the benefits of using separate document libraries, like security trimmed access, keeping similar documents together, usage of content types to track additional metadata for the documents etc.

Although, there are absolutely no issues if your organization keep using 'Shared Documents' document libraries. You can create appropriate folder structures and use custom content types to keep data separate and organized. SharePoint document libraries can contain 30 million items, you will just have to make sure that the data is organized through Folders, or create indexed columns and use them to define views and at each level there are less then 5000 items.

Comment: Its quite ironic that you are posting this answer, as I just got out of a meeting where this was going to be the solution.  Thank you for the Answer!  Spot on! :)